# C# SQLCommand does not write data into db

Tags: c#, sql

I have the following SQL statement (which works if I execute it like this inside my DB):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.PopularityPokemon WHERE Dex_ID = '445')
   UPDATE dbo.PopularityPokemon SET TimesPicked = TimesPicked + 1
ELSE
   INSERT into dbo.PopularityPokemon (Dex_ID, TimesPicked)VALUES('445', 1);
```

I now need to do that from code-behind.

I have the following two parameters:

```
private const int _pickCount = 1;
string dexID
```

The dexID is a parameter given to the function I call.

Doing the standard procedure with making a new Connection and opening it works fine, but I possibly have a syntax error when using SQLCommand:

```
try
{
    using (myConnection)
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = myConnection;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.PopularityPokemon WHERE Dex_ID = @Dex_ID) UPDATE dbo.PopularityPokemon SET TimesPicked = TimesPicked + @PickCount"
                + "ELSE" 
                + "INSERT into dbo.PopularityPokemon (Dex_ID, TimesPicked)"
                + "VALUES(@Dex_ID, @PickCount)";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dex_ID", dexID);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PickCount", _pickCount);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Does your try block catchs an error?

Comment: @NikBo No Errors. dexID and _pickCount also receive the correct values and the connection works.

Comment: @PhilippM. I have already received an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35032320/c-sharp-sqlcommand-does-not-write-data-into-db/35032376#35032376). I was missing some white spaces. Thank you, though^^

Comment: I read `dex_id`, and my first thought was "This poor man is trying to interop with a pokemon app written in [Dexterity](http://dynamicsgpblogster.blogspot.com/2008/12/dexrowid-column.html)... what an odd language choice..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to put a white space at the end of your *every* string that creates your command.

```
command.CommandText = "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.PopularityPokemon WHERE Dex_ID = @Dex_ID) UPDATE dbo.PopularityPokemon SET TimesPicked = TimesPicked + @PickCount "
            + "ELSE " 
            + "INSERT into dbo.PopularityPokemon (Dex_ID, TimesPicked) "
            + "VALUES(@Dex_ID, @PickCount)";
```

Or use verbatim string literal as;

```
command.CommandText = @"IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.PopularityPokemon WHERE Dex_ID = @Dex_ID) UPDATE dbo.PopularityPokemon SET TimesPicked = TimesPicked + @PickCount 
                        ELSE 
                        INSERT into dbo.PopularityPokemon (Dex_ID, TimesPicked) 
                        VALUES(@Dex_ID, @PickCount)";
```

Also don't use `AddWithValue` as much as you can. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overload to specify your parameter type ([`SqlDbType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype)) and it's size.

Answer (score 1):

Modify

```
try
{
    using (myConnection)
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = myConnection;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.PopularityPokemon WHERE Dex_ID = @Dex_ID) UPDATE dbo.PopularityPokemon SET TimesPicked = TimesPicked + @PickCount"
                + "ELSE" 
                + "INSERT into dbo.PopularityPokemon (Dex_ID, TimesPicked)"
                + "VALUES(@Dex_ID, @PickCount)";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dex_ID", dexID);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PickCount", _pickCount);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

TO:

```
try
{
    using (myConnection)
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = myConnection;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.PopularityPokemon WHERE Dex_ID = @Dex_ID) UPDATE dbo.PopularityPokemon SET TimesPicked = TimesPicked + @PickCount"
                + "  ELSE" 
                + "  INSERT into dbo.PopularityPokemon (Dex_ID, TimesPicked)"
                + "  VALUES(@Dex_ID, @PickCount)";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dex_ID", dexID);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PickCount", _pickCount);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```